# Problema ao pegar os Json no AJAX

Tags: ajax, json

Estou tentando recuperar os dados da minha requisição ajax em json, eles chegam corretamente, mas na hora que vou utiliza-los só retorna "undefined".

```
$("#selecionada").on("submit",function(){

  var id_licaoselecionada = $("#prox").val();


  console.log("ID da Licão selecionada =  + "+id_licaoselecionada);

    $.ajax({
      url:'http://localhost/tempus/AJAX/licao/',
      type:'POST',
      data:{idlicao:id_licaoselecionada},
      datatype:'json',
      success:function(data){

        console.log(data)
        console.log("->"+data["nome"]);

        $("#myModal").modal("hide");
        $("#myModal2").modal("show");
        $("#NomeDaLicao").html(data["nome"]);
        $("#ImagemDaLicao").attr('src',data['icone']);
        console.log('Licão escolhida');
      },
      error:function(){
        console.log('Deu ruim, Lição nao carregada');
      }
    }) ;

    return false;
```

Console retorna assim:

- {"idlicoes":"3","0":"3","nome":"Hoje vai","1":"Hoje vai","icone":"assets/images/licoes/paper-plan-1.png","2":"assets/images/licoes/paper-plan-1.png"}
- ->undefined
- licão escolhida

Comment: tente acessar os índices com "." (ponto), ao invés de "[]". Exemplo, data.nome

Comment: continua retornando undefined, antes eu tava botando o success:function(json)  [com json] e  acessando os indices assim com o ponto, mas só dava ''udefinded"

Comment: O que acontece se você fizer o seguinte?

    console.log(JSON.parse(data))

Comment: UHUUL! Deu certo usando o JSON.parse() .Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Legal! Só aceitar a resposta, agora :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que está acontecendo é que você está com uma string nas mãos e tratando-a como um objeto.

Faça da seguinte forma:

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(data.nome); // data["nome"] funciona também, mas a primeira forma é a recomendada.
```